# how do i install Windows 10 from ubuntu onto a separate hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, hard-drive, windows-10

Here's my situation:

I have one hdd with Ubuntu on it (Drive 1) and and one that is empty/formatted (Drive 2.)

What I want to be able to do is install Windows 10 on Drive 2 from using something like gparted, KDE Partition Manager, etc.

How would I do so? Everything else I have tried isn't working (Win10 install tool, iso, bootable usb, DVD, etc.). It would be nice if I didn't have to install anything extra.

Comment: did you NTFS format your drive 2?

Comment: `gparted, KDE Partition Manager, etc.` are just partition managers, It has nothing to do with your Windows installation on another Drive(other than partitioning it according to your choice, But you can do that while installing Windows).

Comment: What do you mean by that Win10 install tool not working? Try to format the partition, e.g., with FAT, and run Win10 launcher again.

Comment: @Hi-Angel i used the Win10 install tool to make a bootable usb.